# Android Studio .idea and .gradle folders be kept in source control?

Tags: android, version-control, android-studio

There are two folders named as `.idea` and `.gradle` in my Android Studio IDE project. Some files in these two folders are easy to conflict with others, such as `.idea\workspace.xml` and `.gradle\1.12\taskArtifacts\*.bin`. Can I remove these two folders `.idea` and `.gradle` out of the source control? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my .gitignore

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
build
```

so basically it ignores workspace.xml and .gradle